# loading a module's block for a custom module in magento

Tags: magento, module, block, adminhtml

I'm getting really frustated about Magento's naming convention. At present, I'm trying to show some "hello world" in the admin section of my module.

The block code is located in

```
 /var/www/magento/app/code/local/Polyvision/Tempest/Block/Adminhtml/View.php
```

The code of View.php:

```
<?php

class Polyvision_Tempest_Block_Adminhtml_View extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function _toHtml()
    {

        $html="hello world";

        return $html;
    }
}
?>
```

So, why can't I load the code via :

```
$x = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('tempest/adminhtml_view');
var_dump($x); // false -> did not work
```

I'm justing getting false as the result. I've tried numerous naming schemes and looked through other code but I cannot understand why it's not working.

Some help would be very very great !

Regards, Alex

Comment: have you tried echo instead of returning $html?

Comment: yes I did. I also added a die() in the constructor to see if it gets loaded but without luck.

Comment: Did you define the block in your modules' config.xml?

Comment: Is your module registered and recognized at all?

Comment: I don't think this will help the question but if making a block in admin you should be extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template` or one of it's family classes.

Comment: That's the part for the block in the config.xml: `global>
        <helpers>
            <Tempest>
                <class>Polyvision_Tempest_Helper</class>
            </Tempest>  
        </helpers>
         <blocks>
            <Tempest>
                <class>Polyvision_Tempest_Block</class>
            </Tempest>
           </blocks>
    </global>  `

Comment: @Luca yes it's working. It's running and I'm displaying at present a blank page via `$this->loadLayout(); $this->renderLayout();`

Answer (score 1):

Well ok. The above code works. My problem was a small typing error in my config.xml

So, for everyone, here's my correct global-section from my config.xml:

```
<global>
        <helpers>
            <tempest>
                <class>Polyvision_Tempest_Helper</class>
            </tempest>  
        </helpers>
         <blocks>
            <tempest>
                <class>Polyvision_Tempest_Block</class>
            </tempest>
           </blocks>
    </global>
```

Thnx for all the advices !